# How to fix magento 2 getUrL

Tags: magento, magento2

I fetched product data by using collection factory from (Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory). Then passed those data in template by block. Data has been fetched successfully but when i try to edit by

```
<a href="<?= $this->getUrl('catalog/product/edit/id/'.$value['entity_id']) ?>">Edit</a>
```

getUrl doesn't generate a valid link.

i want a Url link this
http://localhost/magento2/admin/catalog/product/edit/id/1/key/bfe08a05118e8a063718ecf5804669494dca697b13782ee7a074d9f42344d28a/

but i am getting like this
http://localhost/magento2/admin/catalog/product/edit/key/bfe08a05118e8a063718ecf5804669494dca697b13782ee7a074d9f42344d28a/

As you can see my link doesn't have any ID in between edit and key.
I think i am missing something. Please help

Comment: Try this: $this->getUrl('catalog/product/edit/',[ 'id' => $value['entity_id']]);